# Как работать со шрифтами и иконками в java android разработке?

Tags: java, android-studio

Как работать со шрифтами и иконками в java android разработке?
Вариантов, как я полагаю есть куча, но какие самые лучшие и оптимальные?

Со шрифтами работа такая - android:fontFamily="font face", а если надо кастомный шрифт, то качаешь шрифт и создаешь в res папку font, куда кидаешь скаченные шрифты и там юзаешь.(Если есть другие варинаты, скажите)

А с иконками как? Ведь можно обычные изображения делать(или они будут много весить для иконок) или юзать font-awesome, или есть другие варианты более удобные и оптимальные?

Answer (score 1):

Насчет шифров, есть интересная библиотека. 
https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy

Насчет иконок я использую сайт
https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html

Там вы найдете разные виды иконок, так же для менюшек, шорткатов и других целей. Там большой список стандартных иконок, ну вы можете добавлять и свои туда. Принцип просто генерирует .zip где будут иконки всех разрешений